# How do I check if an error is strconv.NumError using errors.Is

Tags: go, error-handling

I have this error

[image]

The error is of type ParseInt. How do I check for this error
I am assuming I would use `errors.Is` but not sure how I would do it for this case

Comment: It looks like the error type is `*strconv.NumError`, once you verify that, then you can check the `Func`

Comment: Not sure if you are using Go 1.13 or older version but this is worth reading: https://go.dev/blog/go1.13-errors ... it explains `Is` and `As` difference and you can compare those values

Comment: Please do not post images of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://pkg.go.dev/strconv@go1.19.3#NumError

```golang
type NumError struct {
    Func string // the failing function (ParseBool, ParseInt, ParseUint, ParseFloat, ParseComplex)
    Num  string // the input
    Err  error  // the reason the conversion failed (e.g. ErrRange, ErrSyntax, etc.)
}
```

---

> The error is of type ParseInt.

`"ParseInt"` is the name of the *"failing function"*, the one that returned the error. The actual error type is `*strconv.NumError`. You can check for that and the func name like so:

```golang
if e, ok := err.(*strconv.NumError); ok && e.Func == "ParseInt" {
    // do xyz
}
```